# Random generation of multiples of 10 between 10 and 100 in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Apologies if this is a somewhat rudimentary question.
I have attempted to generate random multiples of 10 between 10 and 100 in Excel via the following function:
CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(10,100),10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100).

Of course employing such a method immediately falls out of favour when extending the domain of numbers to something say 10 and a googolplex. Yet, I can't seem to find any other suitable alternative to randomly generating *specifically multiples of 10* between 10 and 100, apart from the aforementioned.
It would be much appreciated if one could assist.

Comment: I'm confused reading your question. What is your expected output? Does your formula work?(for me it gives error). What's your exact problem to solve?

Comment: @MátéJuhász I was requesting for a formula that would reap random multiples of 10 between 10 and 100. I attempted to use the choose and randbetween functions as above, but clearly, it is erroneous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want specifically generate randoms of 10 multiplied by a number in the interval x = [10,100]

You can simply use

```
=RANDBETWEEN(10,100)*10
```

Which generates a number between 10 and 100 and multiplies it by 10. For example 22 * 10.

However your question indicates it wants [1,10] multiplications of 10 multiplied by [10,100] which gives bigger numbers.

For that you can use:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(10,100)*(RANDBETWEEN(1,10)*10)
```

This one gives for example 15 * 20, or 12 * 30, second term will be a multiple of 10.

Or alternatively if you just want values between 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100

You can use `=RANDBETWEEN(1,10)*10`

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
=10*RANDBETWEEN(1,10)
```

[image]

The samples are uncorrelated.  *(no entanglement)*

Comment: Thanks! I completely overlooked this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for "mround", which rounds the result to the nearest multiple. Try this: =MROUND(RANDBETWEEN(10,100),10)